# return the index of a vector when the difference between the index and value satisfies a condition in r

Tags: r, vector

I have been having trouble phrasing this question, so if anyone can edit it up to standard that would be great.

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
 x <- c(1, 2, 5)
```

How do i return the last index where the difference between the value of the vector in that position and the position is = 0.

In this case, I would like to have

```
 2
```

as the difference between the value of the vector and its position for the third element is > 0

```
 x[3]-3.
```

As a side note, this is part of a larger function, where the vector 'x' was built as a vector of values that satisfy a condition (being outside of a range). In this example, the vector 'x' was built as the indexes of the vector

```
 y <- c(1, -0.544099347708607, 0.0330854828196116, 0.126862586350202, -0.189999318205021, 0.0709946572904202, -0.0290039765997793, 0.12201693346217, -0.120410983904152, 0.0974094609584081, -0.119147919464352, 0.0154264136176002, 0.115102403861495, -0.145980255860186, 0.116998886386955, -0.137041816761002, 0.114352714471954, 0.0228895094121642, -0.0679735427311049, 0.0350071153004831, -0.0145366468920295)
```

Which are outside of the range (-.18, .18)

```
 plot.ts(y)
 abline(h = 0.18)
 abline(h = -0.18)
```

Comment: If `x` is an increasing sequence of integers starting at `1`, just find the first gap: `which(diff(x)!=1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Position` function:

```
Position(function(x) {x == 0}, x - 1:length(x), right=T)
```

See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html for more functions.

Or as @Frank said below,

```
Position(`!`, x - 1:length(x), right=T)
```

This is because `0` is falsey and other numbers are truthy.

Comment: Fancier: use `\`!\`` as the function.

Comment: Hm, just looked into `Position` (which this answer introduced me to) and see that it can be quite slow if the index is far away from where we start searching (in this case, from the right since `right=TRUE`). Try `x <- c(1,3:1e7);system.time(Position(\`!\`,x-seq_along(x),right=T)); system.time(tail(which(!(x-seq_along(x))),1))`. This is because `Position` is applying `\`!\`` sequentially to each element of `x-seq_along(x)`. I guess `Position` is defined for use with more complicated predicate functions, that take longer to evaluate.

Comment: @Frank: Mmm, interesting - I guess `which` is faster because it's implemented in the R interpreter?

Comment: You can look at the inside of it by just typing `Position` in. It is faster when (i) the predicate function `f` is complicated and/or un-vectorizable and (ii) the match shows up early in the search along the vector, I think. Try `myfun <- function(x){for(i in 1:1e6){x <- x};TRUE}; system.time(Position(myfun,1:10)); system.time(head(which(sapply(1:10,myfun)),1))`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach:

```
index <- 1:length(x)
max(which(x - index == 0))
#[1] 2
```

Or as the other Frank points out, you could test for equality instead of the difference being 0.

```
max(which(x == index))
```

Comment: `which` always gives its result in sorted order, so `tail` makes a little more sense than `max`. Surprisingly, I see only a small difference in speed (like 15% extra time): `x <- 1:5e8; system.time(max(which(x==seq_along(x)))); system.time(tail(which(x==seq_along(x)),1))`

Comment: @Frank Good point!  I just posted what came to mind first.  I'll leave it in order to avoid duplicating your answer.  Out of curiosity, is it better practice to use `seq_along(x)` over `1:length(x)`?  When I compared the two (using `microbenchmark`) on `x<-1:5e8` the difference was negligible.

Comment: Yeah, seems about the same to me; I've just picked up the habit here on SO. I've seen people use `seq_len(length(x))` which is no better in terms of performance either. These have the advantage of robustness to `x` having length zero (compare `seq_along(NULL);1:length(NULL)`), but in most applications that is obviously not possible. I guess it's some sort of developer mindset, like they would want their function to be robust to arbitrary vector input.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest approach is to test equality, not test for the difference being zero:

```
tail(which(x==seq_along(x)),1)
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also try this

```
tail(which((1:length(x)-x)==0),1)
```